# Must all ssl certificates for a domain be trusted?

Tags: certificates, web-browser, trust

I've read that it's possible to have multiple certificates on one domain. My question is whether all these certificates should be trusted and valid or whether one valid trusted certificate is enough for browsers to trust it.

The context is, I have a WebSocket chat server which provides a trusted certificate from Let's Encrypt through a proxy. However this server also provides an internally managed certificate for identifying it's part of a trusted network. This second certificate is meaningless towards browsers but required for connecting other chat servers to build up a network because the network all trust the root network ca and don't rely on domain names but identities instead.

So in essence, would browsers accept the server since the Let's Encrypt certificate is valid, even though the second certificate is untrusted (since the root ca is not part of the standard trust store).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a single site certificate is transferred during a TLS handshake (i.e. at setup of the HTTPS connection). This certificate must be trustable by the browser, i.e. be valid, not expired, signed by a trusted CA and match the domain from the URL. For this specific connection and client it does not matter what kind of certificates the same server might provide to other clients.

Other clients will probably have similar requirements (at least they should). But they might have a different set of trusted CA so that they might accept a certificate which is issued by an internal CA since they trust this internal CA. Or they might trust a specific self-signed certificate.

Comment: So in essence, I can only send one certificate during the handshake, which means I need to determine which one to send based on who is connected.

Comment: @dsonck92: yes, you need to distinguish the clients. For example they might use a different port, different subdomain... . Most servers will not support to send a different certificate to a different client based on the clients source IP - but only because this is no common use case and not because it is technically impossible.

Comment: @dsonck92 Yup. And the TLS protocol extension used to do that when you have multiple certificates is called Server Name Indicator (SNI).

Comment: @nbering: SNI is used for providing the expected  name in the certificate. If there are different certificates for the same domain SNI will not help to distinguish these because all clients will use the same content in the SNI extension. Only if there are different domains (even subdomains) it will help.

Comment: That can easily be resolved by not using the external domain for the internal network.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich would it be possible to use a client certificate to determine which server certificate would be sent back? Any regular client is expected not to have a client certificate (which means it should send back the official certificate for the domain, as acquired from Let's Encrypt) but the clients that do expect the other certificate all have a client certificate.

Comment: It looks like the server sends it's certificate first, so that's probably a no. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Client-authenticated_TLS_handshake

Comment: SNI is the accepted standard for handling multiple certificates on the same IP address and port. If you want to use anything else, you'll probably be inventing something new, which is dangerous with encryption since even the smallest errors lead to vulnerabilities. Your capabilities will also depend significantly on what software you are using.

Comment: Yes, I might not strictly use SNI but in essence it trusts that the name mentioned in the certificate is what belongs to the server. It's up to the server to protect its private key.

Comment: But, it seems like a different domain or a completely different port might be the best option for the server. In essence the server is proxied behind nginx and talks over WebSocket. This is done to simplify regular clients access to it, since it looks like regular "HTTPS" traffic. However, the clients requiring the specific certificate are expected to have unrestricted networks, so proxying should not be necessary.

Comment: I'd agree that keeping your backplane communication on a separate ip/port would be better. If you have a separate network interface as an option, that would also help protect your backplane from getting overloaded by heavy traffic on the front-end service (and the other way around).

Comment: @dsonck92: A client certificate is requested by the server only after the server certificate has been send. The best way is probably to use different domain names. If this is not an option the second best way might be to use different ports and/or different listener address (i.e. external vs. internal). If you need to select the certificate by the clients source IP you might try to use packet filter rules (iptables etc) to redirect specific source IP to a specific port or address on the local machine so that you can have different listeners with different certificates this way.